# Quartz Library as Embedded Resource does not load correctly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, embedded-resource, quartz

In my app I use external libraries that are added to the executable as Embedded Resource. Then when the app is loaded the following code snippet loads the libraries from the resources so you don't need them in the same folder as separate files. The original code comes from [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition) (the embedded files are in the folder `Resources` that is in the root, hence the `{0}.Resources.{1}`)

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
    string resourceName = string.Format("{0}.Resources.{1}.dll", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name, new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name);
    using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
        return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
    }
};
```

This works fine for a bunch of different libraries. But now I wanted to add the [Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) library V 3.0.7.0. But when the app is run it throws the error

> Object serializer type 'Quartz.Simpl.BinaryObjectSerializer, Quartz'
>   could bot be instantiated.

So it seems there is a (part of) the library missing or not getting loaded correctly (When the entire library is not found on disk or as Embedded Resource you get the `Could not load file or assembly 'Quartz'` error).
Note that the only file needed to run correctly when not embedded is `Quartz.dll`, so there are no files missing.

When I check `args.Name` variables in the above snippet when loaded it gives the following values

```
Quartz, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4
Serilog
Quartz
Quartz
```

So it seems the code tries to load `Quartz` 2 more times, this time without the Version and Culture in the Assembly reference name. And something called `Serilog`?

The only possible answer I found was that it has something to do with it being an `Unmanaged DLL` and that it should still load from disk by first writing the embedded file to disk and then reading it as [seen here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource). But then It would be just as easy to just add the library directly as a separate file.

So has anyone an Idea how to fix the error and getting it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

I specified serialization properties when building the scheduler

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection { 
    { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" } 
};
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
await scheduler.Start();
```

The solution was not to specfy any properties.

```
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
await scheduler.Start();
```